# How to use shortcut "start in" option in windows, using command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I have an executable. I want to start that program in a different folder, rather than starting it in my current folder. Shortcut does have an option where you can specify where you want to start the program. How to do it command line. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? When you use the command line the "start in" folder is whatever folder you where in when you started the program, your question does not make sense as-is, could you re-word it or add more details?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you want to change the current directory before starting a program from the command line.

If that is what you want done just do a `cd your\path\here` followed by a `&` then your program.

For example

```
cd /D C:\Users & dir
```

Will change the active directory to `C:\Users` (the `/D` is so it will change drive letters if necessary) then do the `dir` command in that folder.